# Highcharts - is it support draw scatter line chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use Highcharts to draw a scatter line chart.

following image is an example, but it has same color.

data source format:

```
[
{"ShakeDate":"\/Date(1301068800000)\/","Magnitude":3.3},
{"ShakeDate":"\/Date(1298390400000)\/","Magnitude":4.2,},
{"ShakeDate":"\/Date(1298390400000)\/","Magnitude":5.2,},
]
```

I cannot find a right chart type for this kind of chart.

Anyone can give me some advices?

Thanks.

[image: Magnitude Time chart]

## update:

[HighStock demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jsrockjs/52vuskcv/1/)

## bug: cannot limit max date to current date

Comment: how about a column series with really skinny bars, then a scatter series with fat rectangle looking heads to match the points? same color, of course, and link them using linkedTo: year

Comment: I update the image. This one is what I want. I think the column bar is too fat. I just need a thin line.

Comment: You can control column widht by pointWidth / groupPadding / pointPadding. All of them are documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts. Morever you should set type of xAxis like category.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian. There are many years. The chart is just a demo.

Comment: @Rock "The chart is just a demo" Could you point me where can I find you live demo, because I dont see it

Comment: @Sebastian, I add a demo link and more bug details in the question description.

Comment: And what is your goal, you need to set maxdate on the xAxis or somethign different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `pointWidth` option on `plotOptions` for your series and set it to 1 or 2.

See the fiddle:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/P8Af5/2/)

EDIT: with Highstocks, same thing, use pointWidth:

[Highstock example](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/P8Af5/3/)

Comment: Thanks. Please check the chart again. There are many earthquake records. I think maybe I should use Highstock.

Comment: I change data source to original format, it always use year 1970. see my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vkvC2/

Comment: In same day, there maybe two or more earthquake records.

Comment: You can break Highcharts if you do that. Just run a small script before that processes your data which groups the data by day (so if you have data from today with 3.2 magnitude and then with 4.5 magnitude, create a point for today that is 7.7 magnitude)

Comment: In your given case, it should just show magnitude 4.5, and magnitude 3.2 was covered by 4.5. If there is no data, the date axis cannot show all date. Maybe highstock is not suitable for my case.

Comment: But you said "In same day, there may be two or more earthquake records". I'm confused. And you can set values to 0 on days without data.

Comment: Thanks. If so, there are thousands days data need to set values to 0.

Comment: There's no need to input them if you don't want. Highcharts will automatically not plot on those points.

Comment: for example, I need the date axis from 1920 to 2014, and given data is from 1950 to 1990, but actual axis will from 1950 to 1990, rather than from 1920 to 2014.

Comment: I means I need the axis from 1920 to 2014.

Comment: yes, you can do that as well. In the "x-axis" field, you can specify min and max

Comment: I add a demo link and more bug details in the question description.